# Load data from 2 dim array into tabulator?

Tags: tabulator

Can I load a simple 2 dim array of text or number values into tabulator.

By a two dim array I mean an array of arrays all of the same length. All the examples seem to show an array of structures where each row has to contain the key (aka field or columnName). This seems a very wasteful amount of data when the keys or column names are the same in every row. The other spreadsheet librarys all seem to allow setting up a column model and supply data array values separately. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Handling data in this way is fairly standard representational object model design paradigm that is used widely across a range of front end development scenarios.

These days it is a standard convention in most server side frameworks that when sending a data representation of a database model *(or an array of them)* to or from servers that it is sent as a JSON encoded object of that data. and it is particularly relevant when working with reactive data binding frameworks such as vue or react native which also bind display elements to the properties of these objects.

While it is not as efficient as a raw array of data, it means that object contains more contextual information, and it is the preferred standard in most simple front end data management situations, and they actually efficiency lost in all but the most intensive of compute requirement is negligible.

Tabulator is not primarily intended a spreadsheet library, it is designed for tabular representation of data which is very different, and most table based libraries do require data in the array of objects format.

If you want to import data your array format, you will need to implement a function to map your data into the expected array of objects format before passing it into the table.

Answer (score 0):

```js
new Tabulator('#table-id', {
    data: [[1, 'A', true], [2, 'B', true], [3, 'C', false]],
    columns: [{title: 'index', field: '0'}, {title: 'character', field: '1'},{title: 'bool', field: '2'}]
})
```

> field - Required (not required in icon/button columns) this is the key for this column in the data array

The demo above work fine. If you know the columns of data, just set the column[i].field to the string(i).